# Django MySQL Raw

Tags: python, mysql, django

So I want to get data from my mysql database.

I want to get the street, name,... All my database data. So I want to make a django-mysql-raw query but I don't get my data instead I get: `Data object (1)`

Can anybody help me?

So and this is my code if you need it:

````
# Create your models here.
class Data(models.Model):
    userid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    postcode = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


print("\n\n\n-----------")

for p in Data.objects.raw('SELECT userid FROM Data'):
    print(p)


print("-----------\n\n\n")```
````

Comment: Instead of `print(p)` use `print(p.name)`, `print(p.age)` etc.

Comment: @JPG Thank you! That was the answere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is returning the object that has all the fields so you have to print them individually.